# Return status from Makefile for test command

Tags: makefile

I am trying to capture the return status of the command executed from within the `Makefile`.

**Scenario :**

I have two text files - a.txt and b.txt (both are empty)

If I run the test command, I get the following return status

```
test ! -s b.txt => 0
```

After modifying the contents of text file

```
test ! -s b.txt => 1
```

**Makefile Contents :**

```
test1:
    test ! -s *.txt

test2:
    $(foreach file, $(wildcard *.txt ) , \
    test ! -s ${file};\
)
```

On running `make test1`, I get the following error with return status of 2, irrespective whether the text file is empty or not.

```
/bin/sh: line 0: test: a.txt: binary operator expected
make: *** [test1] Error 2
```

On running `make test2`, I always get the return status of 0, irrespective whether the text file is empty or not.

How could I get the return status of test command from `Makefile` i.e. non-zero if the *.txt is non-zero in size?

Comment: What do you want to *do* with the status? Print it to the screen? Write it to a file? Save it in a shell variable?...

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it and `test` gives that error if you supply to many filenames:

```
tmp> test ! -s a.txt b.txt
-bash: test: a.txt: binary operator expected
```

You might want to use a bash for loop rather than a make foreach loop as so:

```
test1:
   for f in *; do \
        test ! -s "$$f" || exit 1; \
   done
```

For background, your original test:

```
test2:
    $(foreach file, $(wildcard *.txt ) , \
    test ! -s ${file};\
)
```

would expand to:

```
test2:
    test ! -s a.txt; test ! -s b.txt;
```

Notice that the return value of last command (the second `test`) is the return value of the recipe line, and thus make will not fail regardless of whether `a.txt` is empty.  Another side effect is that the make `$(wildcard ..)` is parsed at make read time, and so if any child/sibling targets generated any `.txt`, they would not be expanded/tested when test2 was executed.